# Can I prevent Middle click opening a link to start auto scroll instead?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a component that shows a bunch of user photos inside a container with overflow:auto, each photo is surrounded by an `<a>` tag. There is no space around these images, so if the user ever users the middle click to auto scroll this list of photos it will ALWAYS open the link instead of starting auto scroll. That means auto scroll doesn't work.

Is there a trick that will make a middle click that occurs inside one of these image links to use the auto scroll rather than opening the link in a new tab?

Here is a fiddle that demonstrates the issue :
http://jsfiddle.net/uBrbb/

My original fiddle actually showed the scroll bar - which then allowed the middle click on the scroll bar itself - but in my actual case the scroll bars are hidden with a negative padding so that I can display a custom scroll bar (which I simulated using simple up/down buttons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some complicated things you can do, but if possible, it would be better not to wrap the `<img>` elements in `<a></a>` to begin with, and instead handle the navigation by responding to your own `click()` event. In your `click` event, only perform navigation under the condition `(e.which == 1)` (left click), leaving middle click to the default behavior.

Comment: If I don't use an anchor tag then the images aren't focusable.

Comment: Ok, I think that instead of just removing the `<a>` I'll use a `<button>` instead with an onclick handler. Here is the updated fiddle that demonstrates the fix : http://jsfiddle.net/uBrbb/2/